# SQL delete query in java app takes too long

Tags: java, sql

I'm starting with SQL and trying to mix it with Java app. I have table `ZAMESTNANEC` containing 6 rows.

When I issue the command `delete from ZAMESTNANEC where ID = 7;` in SQL it will delete in no time. A few milliseconds. But when I use this in my Java app, the app will freeze in processing. I waited for 4 minutes and nothing happened (and due to its working state I can't do anything else). Oh and the row wasn't deleted.

I read this topic about deleting but it didn't help me much. In fact it didn't help me at all. 
[oracle delete query taking too much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327190/oracle-delete-query-taking-too-much-time)

I tried to debug it but it's frozen on this command. I don't understand why in SQL it works fine and in Java app it doesn't. Other commands like `SELECT` works fine.

JDBC here - http://pastebin.com/BRh06yc8
Code from button here

```
private void jButtonOdeberZamActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
       try{
            OracleConnector.setUpConnection("xxxxxxxx", 1521, "ee11",
                    "NAME", "PASSWORD");
            conn = OracleConnector.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeQuery("delete from ZAMESTNANEC where ID = 7");
        } catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

Comment: does your table has too many foreign key references?

Comment: Do you have any monitoring tool to see the SQL statement in the database? Also could you show the JDBC code?

Comment: It's hard to say much about what might be causing such behavior when you present neither code nor data.  If you want useful answers then present a [mcve].

Comment: Well, there is not much. In button I have only this command. I've added JDBC (or I hope it's it) into my question. I have no idea how it's made, We've got it from our teacher.

Comment: There is whole model from SQL Data modeler - https://ctrlv.cz/Edko

Comment: `executeQuery` should be used for queries that are expected to return results. Try `executeUpdate` instead and see if that helps. It could be that your app is waiting to receive results which never come back.

Comment: Oh god, you're genius Tom ! It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeQuery` should be used for queries that are expected to return results. Try `executeUpdate` instead and see if that helps. It could be that your app is waiting to receive results which never come back. By [Tom H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5696608/tom-h)

Thank you Tom.